# Is there any good way to refactor an MEAN stack project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, refactoring, mean-stack

Since each part of MEAN stack projects are separated, it's really hard to refactor the whole project. I'm trying to do the following things

1. Modify mongoose schemas
2. Reorganize server code
3. Rename some api calls and parameters
4. Modify Angular code to adapt new APIs

Is there any good ways to do them?

Comment: do you really expect anyone to write procedures or a best practices guide for refactoring multiple environments in a simple answer? Suggest you refactor this question into smaller code specific questions

Comment: I'm expecting maybe there are some tools could help me with the task. :) I'm also expecting some brief ideas about it. I googled a lot but could not find any useful materials.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for any of theese dedicated to MEAN stack. Yeo Man got some generators but these existing are only for creating, not for refactoring. You can still create your own yeo man generator with custom actions or any other server side script that is looking for patterns and changing names according to given configuation file. This can be also automated with gulp or grunt task runners, but its really time-consuming ;)